# How to include jsoncpp library into project on unix?

Tags: c++, cmake, homebrew, static-libraries, jsoncpp

The library I am trying to include is [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp). I am having serious trouble with this. I used the [home-brew](http://macappstore.org/jsoncpp/) install for this library, which is `brew install jsoncpp` (`brew install` is unix version of linux `sudo-apt get`). Normally `homebrew` installs stuff to my path, so I can just use it. I am going off of this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205981/reading-json-files-in-c) here.

```
#include <json/json.h>
```

Returns an error of `10: fatal error: 'json/value.h' file not found`.

I am using cmake because CLion automatically sets it up. Right now it is very basic:

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(Read_JSON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Read_JSON main.cpp)
```

However, for some reason `jsoncpp` cannot be found. How can I include this library in my project?

Comment: What do you mean by "*`jsoncpp` cannot be found*"? Is there a specific error message? CMake error? Compilation error? Linker error? Please add the error log to your question post.

Comment: I am going off of this <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205981/reading-json-files-in-c">example</a> here. I am getting this when I run: `fatal error: 'json/value.h' file not found`

Comment: Try `brew info jsoncpp` to see where it got installed. Then, depending on *where* it was installed, you may need to modify your CMake to include `target_include_directories()` for the jsoncpp include directories, and `target_link_libraries()` so your application can find the jsoncpp libraries.

Comment: @squareskittles I ended up figuring out `cmake` builds so I'm no longer dependent on `brew`. Then yes, the `target_include_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()` is used. However, the project I ended up going with just wanted a cmake directory. So this looked like `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH path/to/cmake)`

Comment: I was facing same issue as this on macos. For me converting `#include <json/json.h>` to `#include "json/json.h"` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in CMake FetchContent capability.
Jsoncpp is available via git repository on GitHub

Here is example how I made with googletest:
https://github.com/adamvm/hello/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

You need just substitute proper addresses and names

Comment: With this method do you need to be connected to the internet every time, only the first time or not at all?

Comment: Here is two control options that are answer to your question: 'FETCHCONTENT_FULLY_DISCONNECTED' and 'FETCHCONTENT_UPDATES_DISCONNECTED'. All capabilities of this module you can check under [link] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FetchContent.html

Answer (score 0):

On mac install with command.

brew install osrf/simulation/ignition-fuel-tools2

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu (since 18.04) you need to install `libjsoncpp-dev`[1] package:

```
sudo apt install libjsoncpp-dev
```

[1] https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libjsoncpp-dev